# Cross-referencing from a master document: "Error: Reference source not found"

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

When creating a cross-reference (in my case a reference to a numbered list item) in a master document to an item in a subdocument, the reference appears to work correctly but when the master document is updated, the reference changes to `Error: Reference source not found`. Example:

Document structure:

```
Master.odt
--> Subdocument.odt
```

Subdocument.odt:

```
1. Clause
2. Clause
```

Master.odm before update:

```
See clause 2.
```

Master.odm after update:

```
See clause Error:Reference source not found
```

After spending hours searching the internet for a solution to no avail, I finally did some experiments to see if I could figure out what is going on internally in the document files. I'm sharing this as a self-answered Q&A in case it is useful for future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Background (skip if uninterested in why the solution works)

Normally when you create a cross-reference within a single document, the content of the list item being referenced will be placed inside `<text:bookmark-start/>` and `<text:bookmark-end/>` tags, with a `text:name` attribute containing a unique identifying number. The cross-reference then uses this attribute so that Writer can search the file to locate the original bookmark and update the contents of the cross-reference. So for example:

```
1. List item
Cross-reference to 1
```

is implemented as follows inside the file's `content.xml`:

```
<text:list-item>
  <text:p text:style-name="P2">
    <text:bookmark-start text:name="__RefNumPara__6070_2182758442"/>
      List item
    <text:bookmark-end text:name="__RefNumPara__6070_2182758442"/>
  </text:p>
</text:list-item>
<text:p text:style-name="P1">
  Cross-reference to <text:bookmark-ref text:reference-format="number-all-superior" text:ref-name="__RefNumPara__6070_2182758442">1</text:bookmark-ref>
</text:p>
```

When Writer comes across the cross-reference during an update, it will search the file for a bookmark tagged with *__RefNumPara__6070_2182758442* and use that to update the cross-reference.

Going back to the example from the question, the situation inside the subdocument's `content.xml` *before* any cross-referencing is something like this::

```
<text:list-item>
    <text:p text:style-name="P1">
        Clause
    </text:p>
</text:list-item>
<text:list-item>
    <text:p text:style-name="P1">
        Clause
    </text:p>
</text:list-item>
```

After making the cross-reference, the master's `content.xml` contains something like this:

```
<text:p text:style-name="P1">
    See clause <text:bookmark-ref text:reference-format="number-all-superior" text:ref-name="__RefNumPara__5977_2182758442">2</text:bookmark-ref>
</text:p>
```

The problem is that the bookmark tagged with *__RefNumPara__5977_2182758442* does not exist in the subdocument. This is because edits made in a master document do not get saved to the subdocument, so the bookmark which is created at the time of the cross-reference is lost upon an update.

### Solution (manual)

The workaround is to first create a cross-reference *from within the subdocument*. So, in the subdocument example from the question, edit the file to include a cross-reference to item number 2, e.g.:

```
1. Clause
2. Clause2
```

where the number "2" after the second word "Clause" is the cross-reference to the item number. This causes LibreOffice to assign it a bookmark with a unique identifier as in the first example in this answer. You can now delete the cross-reference and save the file. The thing that enables this workaround to work is that LibreOffice does not delete the bookmark tags, even if you delete the cross-reference. You can now go ahead and create a cross-reference in the master document. The reference will not be lost after an update because the bookmark exists in the subdocument.

### Solution (automated)

This workaround is a bit annoying, especially if (as in my case) you are trying to draft a complex document with tens or hundreds of cross-references to numbered items in a subdocument. A potential automated solution would be to prepare all numbered items in the subdocument for cross-referencing by running a script which edits `content.xml` and inserts bookmarks inside every `<text-list-item>` tag, being careful to create unique identifiers in a way which is compatible with the open document standard. If at some point I create such a script I will edit this answer to share it.